# properly carbonating my Irish stout

Tags: carbonation

I have just kegged my stout. The fridge currently isn't on, should be powered tomorrow. I've put the co2 up to 25psi to start.

The tank it's still connected and open.

What next?

What temp should I set the fridge too? Do I leave the co2 connected? At what pressure.

I'm totally new to all of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.kegerators.com/carbonation-table.php is my go-to carbonation/temp/pressure table.

Set to the appropriate pressure for the carbonation level appropriate (or desired) based on style, leave the pressure on, and let set for a few days. Once carbonated, drop the pressure down to something to maintain headspace-pressure, and/or use the appropriate line diameter and length to drop the pressure from the keg to the tap down to a small few PSI. http://www.draughtquality.org/ is a great resource for understanding how to maintain a proper draft beer system; it's mostly for pubs, but the core ideas and lessons are still quite suitable for a home draft system.

Comment: What pressure and temp do you normally serve at? It's 3/16 line for serving, about 2-3' long.

Comment: For a stout, by style, I'd use something like ~2 volumes. My fridge is about 45°F. Based on that table, 9 pounds of pressure should do the trick. 2-3' of line isn't going to drop the pressure much, so maybe dial it back to 3-4 PSI for serving. I usually just adjust on the fly to get the right pour.

Comment: Thanks, I'm hooking up the Ranco ETC-111000 to the freezer tonight so I'll be able to set this to the exact temp easily.

Comment: I set it to 45 @ 9psi. How long until it's carbed and drinkable?